# Using loops instead of substring. Array loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, substring

I'm not sure if this is a stupid question but can I write something that returns a substring without using substrings?

for e.g. usually you'd write something like this:

```
var str = "Hello world";
var res = str.substring(1, 4);
```

Can i use a loop instead to do it? Or is that not possible? How would i start to do it? I know it's something to do with arrays.

would it be something like `A[i]` and adding loops?

Comment: You can...It is possible...Use `+=` for concatenation...Try this: `var str = "Hello world";
var op = '';
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  op += str[i];
}
alert(op);
var res = str.substring(1, 4);
alert(res);
`

Comment: A string like `var str = "Hello world"` can be treated as an array.  So, if you run `str[0]` you will get `"H"`.

Comment: It is not a stupid question but may I ask [why](http://xyproblem.info/) you would try to do this?

Comment: @RayonDabre That's fantastic, just what i needed thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this if you really want to use an array and indexes:

```js
var str = "Hello world";
var res = "";
var first_char = 1; // inclusive
var last_char = 4; // exclusive


for(var i = first_char; i < last_char; i++) {
 res += str[i];
}

alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

> but can I write something that returns a substring without using
>   substrings?

Not sure why you don't want to use `substring`, hope there is no issue with `slice`

```
str.slice(1,5); //outputs "ello"
```

or, if you want to make it more complicated then

```
str.split("").splice(1,4).join(""); //outputs "ello"
```

this one treats str as array and then filter out the data based on index

```
str.split("").filter( function(value, index){ if ( index >= 1 && index < 5 ) {return true;} else {return false;} } ).join(""); //outputs "ello"
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the question is a learning exercise.

Comment: I'm missing a jQuery solution!